# Issue related to ReturnUrl concept in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, returnurl

I have developed a website in mvc3 which uses ReturnUrl concept. In this we have implemented authorization such that when user is not logged in and tried to access a authorized page, then that user is redirected to login page.

For example, if we have a url http://mydemosite.com/User/List, and the user accessing the link is not logged in. Then user is redirected to login page with return url as http://mydemosite.com/Account/login/?ReturnUrl=%2fUser%2fList. So now when user logs in using valid credentials, website is redirected to User/List page.

My question here is if I browse to the below url

http://mydemosite.com/Device/List/?ReturnUrl=%2fUser%2fList

It shows me 401 - unauthorize error. But if i change the Url to

http://mydemosite.com/User/List/?ReturnURL=%2fUser%2fList

Notice that I changed the query parameter ReturnUrl to ReturnURL, after this change I get redirected to the requested page after authentication is complete.

Could anyone let me know why the issue occurs?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't because the controllers are completely different? mydemosite.com/User vs. mydemosite.com/Device...

Comment: You can put any controller and action there which needs to be authorized